# conditions for divs in drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have 2 droppable divs called drop1 and drop2, and 2 draggable elements called ans1 and ans2. I want to make an alert when ans1 is inside drop1 and ans2 is inside drop2. Both conditions have to be fulfilled (not caring about which is fulfilled first) in order for the alert to come out.

```js
$("#ans1, #ans2").draggable({
revert: "valid",
cursor: "move"
});

$("#drop1, #drop2").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    if ($("#ans1", $("#drop1")) && $("#ans2", $(".drop2"))) {
      alert("correct");
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="drop1" class="b1" style="background-color: white; border: solid; height: 6vw; width: 13vw; border-radius: 7px">
</div>
<div id="drop2" class="b1" style="background-color: white; border: solid; height: 6vw; width: 13vw; border-radius: 7px">
</div>

<div id="ans2" style="background-color: white; border: solid; cursor: move; height: 6vw; width: 13vw; border-radius: 7px">
 a change
</div>
<br/>
<div id="ans1" style="background-color: white; border: solid; cursor: move; height: 6vw; width: 13vw; border-radius: 7px">
chemical reaction system
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2018/sergei-eisensteins-120th-birthday-5380775741489152.2-s.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `accept` option and `ui.draggable.text()` of the `droppable()` function

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(".drag-div>div").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  cursor: "move"
})

$(".drop-div>div").droppable({
  accept: ".drag-div>div",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).text(ui.draggable.text());
    if ($("#drop1").text() == $("#ans1").text() && $("#drop2").text() == $("#ans2").text()) {
      alert("correct");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="drop-div">
  <div id="drop1" class="b1" style="background-color: white; border: solid; height: 6vw; width: 13vw; border-radius: 7px">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div id="drop2" class="b1" style="background-color: white; border: solid; height: 6vw; width: 13vw; border-radius: 7px">
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="drag-div">
  <div id="ans2" style="background-color: white; border: solid; cursor: move; height: 6vw; width: 13vw; border-radius: 7px">
    a change
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div id="ans1" style="background-color: white; border: solid; cursor: move; height: 6vw; width: 13vw; border-radius: 7px">
    chemical
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i need the alert to come out only when ans1 is in drop1 and ans2 is in drop2. When both conditions are fulfilled, only then the alert comes out.

Comment: Just a suggestion , you probably want to use $.trim on `$("#drop1").text()` etc and (MAYBE) use the `===` operator instead of  `==`